# Как сделать редактируемый документ с разбивкой на страницы в WPF?

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

В WPF нет готовых для этого контролов, либо читай либо редактируй, но не вместе. Что предложите, писать свой контрол, как лучше это сделать или есть другие варианты. Добавлю что нужно иметь возможность вывода документа на печать.

Answer (score 2):

Готовые варианты безусловно есть, да RichTextBox довольно сильно поменялся со времен WinForms и на очень многое способен.

Печать тоже дело нехитрое, хотя конечно её и приходится писать руками, особенно постраничный вывод, но и примеров тьма.

Весь вопрос в том, какая перед Вами стоит задача. Если все ограничивается редактированием, чтением, печатью, то что-то готовое искать не стоит, а если же это лишь небольшой кусок серьезной системы (документооборот тот же), то готовое в руки и дальше работать над остальным функционалом и логикой.

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно отметил [@Spawn](/users/12111/spawn), вы можете использовать `RichTextBox` в качестве контейнера `FlowDocument`. Если его функциональность вас не устраивает (например, вы хотите разбивку на страницы), вам придётся написать свой контрол, который будет включать FlowDocument для отображения контента, а вашему контролу придётся анализировать пользовательский ввод, и модифицировать FlowDocument соответственно.